# Updating children of SimpleCursorTreeAdapter

Tags: android, expandablelistadapter, simplecursortreeadapter

I am using a SimpleCursorTreeAdapter to display data in database. I am using loaders to manage all the cursors. Everything works fine. But there are some images in each of the child views. This causes a noticeable stutter when scrolling. So I want to use an asynctask to decode the images in background. Something like (pseudocode):

```
@Override                                                                                                        
protected void bindChildView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isLastChild) {                   
        super.bindChildView(view, context, cursor, isLastChild);                                                 
        String imgFile = cursor.getString(MyDatabaseHelper.FILE_INDEX);                                          
        new asyncLoadImage().execute(imgFile);                                                                   
}                                                                                                                

private class asyncLoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {                                           

        @Override                                                                                                
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... arg0) {                                                        
                String imgFile = arg0[0];                                                                        
                return Utils.getBitMap(imgFile);//psuedocode                                                     
        }                                                                                                        

        @Override                                                                                                
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bm) {                                                                
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mCtx);                                                       
                imageView.setTag(mID);                                                                           
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);                                                                    
                //ok got the imageview. where do I append it ??                                                  
        }                                                                                                        
}
```

By the time the imageview is ready in onPostExecute() function, the view provided in bindChildView might have been recycled and pointing to some different child element. How do I determine where to append the imageview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't append. You need the `ImageView` there anyway. Have the `ImageView` use a placeholder image, that you replace with the final image when it is ready.

Second, consider using an existing library that knows about `Adapter` recycling, such as [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso). Admittedly, I don't know if Picasso has support for `ExpandableListAdapter`, as I rarely use `ExpandableListView`.

If you determine that there is no suitable library, you'll need some logic in your `getChildView()` and/or `getGroupView()` methods that can deal with recycling and your background work. One fairly simple approach is to tuck the URL of the image needed by the `ImageView` in the tag of the `ImageView` via `setTag()`. Your `onPostExecute()` can then compare the URL it just downloaded with the URL from the `ImageView` tag, and if they do not match, do not update the `ImageView`. This means that you will download some images unnecessarily, so a more sophisticated approach will arrange to cancel the `AsyncTask` that is downloading the image. And I am sure that there are other approaches as well.

Comment: I too thought of using the setTag approach. But I could not figure out how to get list of views that I could loop over to find the required view. Moreover could there be race condition ? What if the user scrolls away just after I have determined which view to update ? This is driving me crazy :-(

Comment: You said you rarely use ExpandableListView. What other UI patterns can be used to group data ?

Comment: @user3459908: "But I could not figure out how to get list of views that I could loop over to find the required view" -- sorry, but I don't understand this. "This is driving me crazy" -- which is why I recommend using an existing library that handles the pattern, if you can find one that works with `ExpandableListAdapter`. "What other UI patterns can be used to group data ?" -- many apps use sequential `ListViews`. If you use Gmail, they do not use an `ExpandableListView` for showing labels and conversations; they use separate a `ListView` for each.

Comment: Ah! I get it now .. I can simply pass the view in the asynctask constructor with the tag set. No need to find all views and iterate over them.

Comment: I ended up using code from here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html. Works well.